# Delete row from DataFrame where value is present in another column and 'col3' == Missing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am dealing with this example DataFrame:

```
         A      B        C
1       Cat      0     Missing
2       Dog    Dog     Match
3       Cat    Cat     Match
```

I would like to remove row[1] as it meets the condition of `'C' == "Missing"`
and `'A'.isin('B')`

Could use help writing this.

Currently I have tried;

```
if df['C'] == "Missing":
   df = df.loc[~df.A.isin(B)]
```

But no luck thus far. Thanks.

Comment: For row 1, are you checking if 'Cat' appears anywhere in column B, or in exactly row 1 column B?

Comment: df.replace({'Missing',np.nan}).dropna()..

Comment: @thesilkworm, I am looking for a value in row 1 in column A  anywhere in column B, also where row 1 column C equals "Missing"

Comment: I think my answer should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
b = df['B']
df = df[~((df['A'].isin(b)) & (df['C'] == 'Missing'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

try `df.loc[~(df['C'] == "Missing") & (df['A'].isin(df['B'].unique()))]`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.